# MySql order by related with today's date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column and I am using order by clause.

I want to show the records near to today's date at top and then all records with the past at bottom.

I want to do this with single query.

I tried this

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff  FROM `post` order by diff
```

Problem with this query is this will show records with past first and if I use descending then the records far from today will be on top.

How I can achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if the date field cannot contains date in the future so use `SELECT * FROM post order by date DESC`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do it something like:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff  FROM `post`
order by CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, diff
```

Which will force any dates in the past to sort after the current date or dates in the future.

Comment: Just wondering, if it's possible to make past dates sort in descending order so that the most recent dates show right after future dates.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff  FROM `post` order by ABS(diff)
```

Comment: That will interleave past and future events, based on their distance from now. That doesn't sound like "all records with the past at bottom."

Comment: It will mix the records from past with future. I want all records with past at bottom.

Comment: Combining this and what @Dami

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ORDER BY` Descendly  like this:

```
 SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff  
 FROM `post ORDER BY diff DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

why no tjust plain old date order?

```
 SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff  
 FROM `post ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want results that are too far in the future, simply remove these results from the result set:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff FROM `post` 
WHERE `date` < date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining [@hkutluay' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396406/3210309) and the [accepted answer from @Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396446/3210309) yields the expected results where the posts go from upcoming closes to today then past post again closes to today first:

```sql
SELECT
 *,
 DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) AS diff 
FROM `post`
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
 ABS(diff)
```

Example result:

```
Assuming that today is 1.1.2022

P1 1.1.2022
P2 1.2.2022
P3 31.12.2021
P4 31.11.2021
...
```